# Can't upgrade to GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-legacy

I'm trying to upgrade my bootloader from GRUB to GRUB2 following this guide

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading
```

Problem is that at the end of the process when i do

```
sudo upgrade-from-grub-legacy
```

It will appear an error message and it will stop

```
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME is required
```

System is a cloud based service (QuadraNet) where they provide VPS with ubuntu 16.04x64bit preloaded. At the moment both Grub-legacy and Grub2 are present, but only Grub-legacy is loading.

Comment: What distro are you running? If it's Ubuntu 14.04 or later you should already be running GRUB2.

Comment: @Batcastle: that is not true.  I have a Xenial system booting off grub-legacy.

Comment: @MAV If you upgraded that system from Precise that wouldn't suprise me. I was talking as in if you installed 14.04 or later it SHOULD be using GRUB2 by default.

Comment: It's still not true, as you can deviate from the default.  In any case, your original comment is definitely wrong and might mislead coming here, so I pointed out your error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message on debian.  I couldn't get the message to leave.

(Beware that if something goes wrong, you could have a system that won't boot.  Maybe download a live USB stick.  )

under root / sudo -i run:

```
apt remove grub-legacy
apt install grub2 grub-pc
cd /boot/grub ; mv menu.1st  menu.1st.save
grub-install /dev/sda --recheck   # repeat this if you have any mirrored disks
update-grub
```

Which is basically kind of a manual install of grub.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old problem, but it was [only fairly recently fixed in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/943387).  [All current Ubuntu LTS as well as Ubuntu+1 impish are still affected](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/grub2/+bug/1879496).  A very simple and maintainer-approved [patch is available](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=943387;filename=upgrade-from-grub-legacy-dpkg-maintscript-helper.patch;msg=5).